# Bash Loops and Text Editors

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a handful of servers which have a log file I'd like to monitor. Because the project is new and most of the errors so far have been unique, I'd like to monitor these logs manually for a while. I was hoping to save a little bit of time by putting all of the IPs to monitor in a text file, then doing something simple like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ip; do
    scp user@"$ip":/var/log/file.log ./
    nano -w file.log
    rm -f file.log
done < ips.txt
```

However, Nano (and Vi) absolutely flip out, as it appears the Bash loop does not wait for me to exit them before continuing on to the next command.

How do I make the Bash loop wait for me to exit the text editor before continuing? Feel free to be technical in explaining the answer; part of the reason I'm asking is because I don't know enough about Bash to know why this is happening, but I'd like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what it is. Because you are redirecting the input to the while loop, nano no longer sees your terminal at its stdin. Try replacing

```
nano -w file.log
```

with

```
nano -w file.log < /dev/tty
```

Comment: Excellent; thanks! Although I vaguely knew about input/output redirection, I'd never stopped to consider what that magical while loop formula I oh so frequently copied was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider...

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ip; do
    scp user@"$ip":/var/log/file.log ./
    nano -w file.log && rm -f file.log
done < ips.txt
```

The `&&` will wait for a command to complete successfully (return with 0) before doing the statements to the right of it.

edit: woops, after actually running the command, @glennjackman is right. 
Also, if you want to learn some bash stuff, consider reading [TLDP's beginner Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html) and [TLDP's Advanced Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: You mean `nano -w file.log && rm -f file.log` -- get rid of the `$()`.

Comment: @glennjackman Neither of those quite work. The poster's solution gets "Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM" just after SCPing the file, yours actually opens it in Nano before "Received SIGHUP or SIGTERMustify". Either one bombs out at that point, although the $() leaves my session in a strange state.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a call to `time`

Example:

```
time nano -w file.log
```

There'll be some output spewed, which I suppose you could redirec to /dev/null if you like, but "time" should be considered to still be running, unlike the way the editors behave.

Comment: That's a nifty command I was unfamiliar with, but plugging it into the loop in my original question does not cause it to wait until completion -- Nano still gets a prompt "Received SIGHUP or SIGTERMustify" then time's output is displayed (0.489s later, by the way). I'm beginning to wonder if there's some strange Bash configuration at play here; the loop doesn't seem to be waiting for these commands to complete like people are expecting. Have you tried this on your local machine? Even a 127.0.0.1 SCP should demonstrate it...